# Folders belong to owner not in my system's account

Tags: windows-10, permissions

I'm working on a non-domain PC, after install some apps using Windows Winget, I need to access that folder, and surprisely, I can't list those directories content.
As you can see below, the folder is belong to `TrustedInstaller`, but it's not my system account.
Where did it come from, and how should I list those folders content without break winget function (change permission/owner)?

[image: folder belong to user not in my system]

Comment: You normally do not need to use this folder. You can list the files using Tree Size Pro. That works. You can try changing the advanced security properties of the folder. I do not recommend this.

Comment: Yes, I'm worry that change advanced security properties (change owner) will make winget stop working. I need to uninstall a package, but winget doesn't has uninstall feature, nor I can't find the uninstaller.exe for this app (Quiclook)

Comment: Yes.   Tree Size does not change the properties but does allow viewing.

Comment: if you want to uninstall a package installed by Microsoft package manager, maybe you can try with command: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/ps-reference/ps-ref-uninstall-package

Answer (score 1):

Windows App folder is a very highly secured folder. It should not be use except by properly designed Apps that go in there.

Winget is a valid installation manager.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/

So if you need to view the folder and not modify or change the permissions, use Tree Size Professional. Tree Size is an excellent app and will allow you to view the folder contents. You must run Tree Size in Admin Mode to do this. But nothing is altered.